# Can't Open Microphone - API issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-edittext, android-manifest

I am working on a simple app which opens activities when a button is pressed etc. However my main activity is based on PocketSphinx API and my second activity uses `onClickListener` and Google's Speech to text API.

When I run each of these activities as individual apps they work perfectly.  When I have then integrated them into one app and assigned correct button presses etc the app runs fine however when in the Speech to Text activity, the button `gVoice` opens up the speech prompt but instantly says 'Can't Open Microphone'

I have attached below my Manifest file, part of the Main Activity file and also the full Gvoice activity.

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="PocketSphinxActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    //every new activity needs to be listed here:
    <activity android:name=".Gvoice"></activity>
</application>
```

Top part of the MainActivity File:

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;
import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;

public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener
{

private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";

/* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
private static final String KEYPHRASE = "open voice command";   //adjust this keyphrase!

private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

ListView lv;
TextView tv;
EditText a;
Button b;
Button c;

Boolean isDone = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    // Prepare the data for UI
    captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
            .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
    c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogin);

    // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
    // so we execute it in async task

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
//etc...
```

Full Gvoice java File:

```
package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Gvoice extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ListView lv1;
static final int check = 1111;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gvoice);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LVGVoiceReturn);
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GVoice);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
Intent i1 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Please Repeat Again");
    startActivityForResult(i1, check);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

Just wondering if there is an issue with any of the package names etc, I have got permissions set for internet and record audio etc.  Hoping there is someone knowledgeable to assist me to fix this issue out asap please.